# How to fill particular block in UIImageView by touching anywhere in the block area?

Tags: iphone, core-image

I have a UIImageView as displaying below.Every blocks in the Image are of different sizes.And not defined any bound area of Image.We have to fill particular block by touching anywhere in the block area.Let us suppose I clicked one white block then it should be filled with specific color.My Problem is that how can we detect boundary of block to fill.
We will get location of touch but by comparing to which boundary I can find out which area to be filled as it is just a image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Finally I have solved my problem.Using CGContext.I have written the following code to  fullFill the requirement.

```
    @implementation FillBoxViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [_imgView sizeToFit];
    [_imgView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pt=[touch locationInView:self.view];

    CGContextRef ctx;
    CGImageRef imageRef = [_imgView.image CGImage];

    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

    if (pt.y<height)
    {
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

        unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);

        NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
        NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;

        NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                     bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
        CGContextRelease(context);

        //GET PIXEL FROM POINT

        int index = 4*(width*(round(pt.y))+(round(pt.x)));

        NSLog(@"index is %i",index);

        int R = rawData[index];
        int G = rawData[index+1];
        int B = rawData[index+2];

        NSLog(@"%d   %d   %d", R, G, B);

        //IF YOU WANT TO ALTER THE PIXELS

        for (int row=pt.y-20; row<=pt.y+20;++row)
        {
            for (int col=pt.x-20; col<=pt.x+20;++col)
            {
                int r,g,b;
                int byteIndex=4*(width*(round(row))+(round(col)));
                r=rawData[byteIndex];
                g=rawData[byteIndex+1];
                b=rawData[byteIndex+2];

                if ((r<R+10&&r>R-10) && (g<G+10&&g>G-10) && (b<B+10&&b>B-10)) {
                    rawData[byteIndex]=(char)(255);
                    rawData[byteIndex+1]=(char)(0);
                    rawData[byteIndex+2]=(char)(0);
                }
            }
        }

        ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,
                                    CGImageGetWidth( imageRef ),
                                    CGImageGetHeight( imageRef ),
                                    8,
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow( imageRef ),
                                    CGImageGetColorSpace( imageRef ),
                                    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast );

        imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);

        UIImage* rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];  

        CGContextRelease(ctx);  

        _imgView.image = rawImage;

        free(rawData);
    }

    NSLog(@"touch detected at location (%f,%f)",pt.x,pt.y);
}

@end
```

Apply condition to check color at point and check changing of color that will stop filling rect out of boundary.As the image has not exactly fix color in the block that's why image is looking like that and I have to use checking color between range of RGB color get from touching on the Image.